# Stripe update of subscription generating error

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I am using the gem stripe v4.0.3.  If I retrieve a subscription, then I can cancel it using:

```
subscription.cancel_at_period_end = true
subscription.save
```

According to the [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing), I should also be able to do this with the command:

```
subscription.update(cancel_at_period_end: true)
```

but this generates an error:

```
Failure/Error: subscription.update(cancel_at_period_end: true)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `update' for #<Stripe::Subscription:0x00007fcda95efd20>
```

Why is this?

Comment: I don't see this method [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=ruby). Retrieve a subscription, set a property and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe support confirmed that there is an error in the documentation example. They also stated there were two ways to do this

```
sub = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve("sub_xxxyyyzz")
sub.cancel_at_period_end = true
sub.save

Or

Stripe::Subscription.update("sub_xxxyyzz",{:cancel_at_period_end => true})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method as update for subscription object.
If you want to cancel the subscription on period end, you need to call the subscription services cancel method. You will need to pass that your customer and subscription id, and then use the cancelAtPeriodEnd flag (set it to true).

Comment: As you said, if you want to cancel the subscription at the end of the current billing period, we have to update with cancel_at_period_end flag as true.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing

    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a')
    subscription.update(cancel_at_period_end: true)
There may be issue in stripe gem.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the documentation rather than an issue with the gem. `Stripe::Subscription.update(cancel_at_period_end: true)` is the preferred approach per the [test suite](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/test/stripe/subscription_test.rb#L38)`. This also saves an API round trip to retrieve an Subscription that you're only going to cancel.